# Using numpy for first time hit "ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, concatenation

Today I installed my first package, numpy, and wanted to try it out. So I found
this article, [Bayes’ theorem implementation in python](http://blog.bridge-global.com/bayes-theorem-implementation-in-python), and wanted to experiment. I hit an error:

CODE:

```
import numpy as np

x_red = np.array([1,2,3])

y_red = np.array([1,2,3])

z_red = np.array([1,2,3])

red_points = np.array(zip(x_red,y_red,z_red))

x_blue = np.array([1,2,3])

y_blue = np.array([1,2,3])

z_blue = np.array([1,2,3])

blue_points = np.array(zip(x_blue,y_blue,z_blue))

points = np.concatenate([red_points,blue_points])
```

ERROR on last line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tmp.py", line 19, in <module>
    points = np.concatenate([red_points,blue_points])
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

I was hoping to run numpy as a black box for now, but as a newbie to python have no idea how to debug a 'package error'.

It may be that something changed with python 3.6 (the code was using the old print statement).

Any answers/comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Try creating red_points without the zip.  Check its shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `list` on the `zip` function. In python 3 [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator.

**Here:**

```
import numpy as np
x_red = np.array([1,2,3])
y_red = np.array([1,2,3])
z_red = np.array([1,2,3])
red_points = np.array(list(zip(x_red,y_red,z_red)))  # <- here
x_blue = np.array([1,2,3])
y_blue = np.array([1,2,3])
z_blue = np.array([1,2,3])
blue_points = np.array(list(zip(x_blue,y_blue,z_blue)))  # <- and here
points = np.concatenate([red_points,blue_points])
```

Comment: Why does `np.array` accept such an iterator but do nothing useful with it?

Comment: I guess there is a good reason for it. But I'm not the person to ask I'm afraid

Comment: It seems to be the empty-shape (0-dimensional) case mentioned in hpaulj's answer.  I guess it's nice to have a scalar be a special case of an array, but it's not consistent: `np.array(1)+np.array(3)` yields `np.int64(4)`, for example.

Comment: @DavisHerring Good work, Yes that is odd, why not return an array? Interesting!

Comment: There's a certain overlap between `1`, `np.int32(1)` and `np.array(1)`, but they aren't identical.  Class is is different for a start, and with it the available methods.

Answer (score 2):

`np.array` takes a iterable like a list, but not an iterator or generator.

```
In [26]: red_points = np.array(zip(x_red,y_red,z_red)) 
In [27]: red_points
Out[27]: array(<zip object at 0xab7d9b2c>, dtype=object)
```

The result is a 0d array containing one item, that zip object.  In Py2, `zip` produced a list, in Py3 you have to `list` it.

```
In [28]: red_points = np.array(list(zip(x_red,y_red,z_red)))
In [29]: red_points
Out[29]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

`np.array(...)` takes a list of lists like that displayed in `Out[29]`.  That's one of the most common ways of using it.

Using `zip(...)` like this is effectively a way of transposing the inputs.  `numpy` can also do that transpose:

```
In [31]: red_points = np.array((x_red,y_red,z_red))
In [32]: red_points
Out[32]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
In [33]: red_points.T
Out[33]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

`np.stack` also works.  With the default `axis=0` it acts just like `np.array`.

```
In [34]: red_points = np.stack((x_red,y_red,z_red),axis=1)
In [35]: red_points
Out[35]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

While 0d arrays aren't common, it helps to understand them when they do occur.  Get in the habit of checking the `shape` and `dtype` of arrays when you get errors or unexpected results.

---

There is a `fromiter` that works with an iterator, but it requires a `dtype` - and only produces a 1d array.

```
In [39]: np.fromiter(zip(x_red,y_red,z_red),'i,i,i')
Out[39]: 
array([(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

Part of why `np.array` expects a full list, is that it looks at the whole thing before deciding things like dtype and shape.

Comment: Thx. Certainly easier to see what numpy is doing when statements like `print(red_points,red_points.shape,red_points.dtype)` work!

Comment: `red_points = np.stack([x_red,y_red,z_red],axis=1)` works and is a 'clean' alternative.